# Can't use DBNull in .NET Standard 1.4?

Tags: c#, .net, dbnull, .net-standard-1.4

I am creating a class library that will be used in a WPF project and a .NET Core project.

For the following code:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        private void MyFunction(object o)
        {
            if (o == DBNull)
            {
                //ommitted
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> The name 'DBNull' does not exist in the current context

This is a .NET Standard Class Library Project created in Visual Studio 2017.

Both my .NET Core project and WPF Project allow the use of DBNull.

Comment: Why not using `null`? Anyways, did you import necessary package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the NuGet package `System.Data.Common` to your project to be able to use `DBNull` in `netstandard1.4` via the NuGet package manager or via console:

```
dotnet add package System.Data.Common
```

In .NET Standard 2.0, it will be available automatically.